# CSS-responsive website for specific CSS formatting issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, hamburger-menu

I've been grinding through this site and now I'm running into an issue making my site responsive. (I choose not to use a CSS framework so that I can better understand CSS). However, my brain is fried and I was hoping someone could help me make this page responsive on mobile and tablet. I still have some JavaScript to add, but want to try and accomplish the following in CSS:

1. Hamburger menu for links on top
2. responsive site for mobile and tablet view
3. I am going to also add modals for each link to display data. I'm going to figure this out myself, but if you have any initial steps to share, that would be appreciated as well.

Any assistance is appreciated

Here is the link to my code: https://codepen.io/YLCPapi/pen/YzdLVaW

**CSS:**

```
/* Google Fonts */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&display=swap");
/* font-family: 'Lilita One', cursive; */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&family=Lobster&display=swap");
/* font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; */

/* Global */
*{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(155, 198, 233);
}

/* header */
h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'Lilita One', Cursive;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.contactBar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 100px;
}

.contactBar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.contactBar ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 65px;
    align-items: center;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: ease 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

a:hover{
    color: rgb(240, 240, 155);
}

/* Image section */
#midSection{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.textSection{
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 128);
    height: 368px;
    color: rgb(253, 252, 252);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 105px rgb(56, 149, 224);
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.top{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font
```

Comment: Here is my deployed site on Github which is a better view than codepen: https://papicly.github.io/Dinner_Generator/

Comment: This is a good article on how to build a basic [responsive (hamburger) menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I build responsive websites.

1. Build the stylesheet to implement the **mobile** view initially.
2. Add @media rules to override various styles for wider screens where necessary, in increasing order of width.

I find the following widths to be the most useful in @media rules:

1. **Less than 500 pixels** — base rules for phones held vertically. Don’t use a media query for these rules.
2. **500 pixels or more** — any overrides required for phones held horizontally. Use `@media (min-width: 500px)`.
3. **750 pixels or more** — any overrides required for tablets held vertically. Use `@media (min-width: 750px)`.
4. **1000 pixels or more** — any overrides required for either tablets held horizontally, or desktops. Use `@media (min-width: 1000px)`.

Here is a quick sample. Make sure to use the **full page** link so that you can test the responsiveness easily.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* base rules for phones held vertically */
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

/* overrides for phones held horizontally */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
}

/* overrides for tablets held vertically */
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  }
}

/* overrides for tablets held horizontally, and desktops */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/301/500/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/302/500/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/304/500/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/305/500/200">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'll be saving this for sure!....did you have any recommendations for my CSS code?

Comment: I recommend you do the tutorial on building responsive menus which I sent you a link to in my comment on your question.

Comment: 